# Variable to set end of backwards substring can not be a number?

Tags: python

What if I want to take a substring from a word, starting at the end and going to the index stored in a variable.

word[4:0:-1] does not include the first letter but word[4::-1] does include the first letter. What if I am determining the final letter with a variable called "a". Is it only possible by setting "a" to None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the OP means that the index is stored in variable a.

In which case he could do something like:

```
a=0
word[4:(None if a==-1 else a):-1]
```

Or more generally:

```
word="Konichiwa"
a=0
word[len(word):(None if a==-1 else a): -1]
```

Comment: I think it should be ">= 0" because word[:0:-1] returns all but the last letter and word[:None:-1] includes the last letter as well.

Comment: Right you are, Dima. That's what I get for  posting untested code. Updated version should be good.

Comment: I think I'd use: [4:(None if a == -1 else a):-1], so that the indexes are the same as they are meant to be according to Python, and -1 is where the slice "should" end.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I am determining the final letter with a variable called "a"

Then you don't need reversing at all. This will do:

```
a = word[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I was thinking it was something odd in all this issue, the reverse is not necessary at all. Nice view

Comment: By final letter, I mean first letter in the original string, last in the output. If the string is "Hello", I would like to be able to choose if I want "olle" or "olleH".

Answer (score 1):

Taken from your comment:

> I would like to be able to choose if I want "olle" or "olleH"

I assume you want a function with signature something like:

```
def reverse_string(s:str, include_first_lett=True) -> str:
```

So just do:

```
def reverse_string(s:str, include_first_lett=True) -> str:
    end_idx = None if include_first_lett else 0
    return s[:end_idx:-1]

    # or more verbosely
    # if include_first_lett:
    #     return s[::-1]
    # else:
    #     return s[:0:-1]
    #
    # or EVEN more verbosely, but more readable to someone who hasn't spent
    #   too long memorizing the slicing syntax...
    # if include_first_lett:
    #     return s[::-1]
    # else:
    #     return (s[1:])[::-1] 


>>> reverse_string("Hello")
'olleH'
>>> reverse_string("Hello", False)
'olle'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the final letter you don't need asing None at all, following your example, do this:

```
word = "Hello"
a = word[4:0:-1]
a = a[:1]



   a
=> 'o'
```

But you are reversing the string... it's not necessary at all